# How to Optimize the loading time in FUllcalendar

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have used the below code to show the calendar but it takes too much of time load the calendar.

Code:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 events: [
                        <apex:repeat value="{!Allevent}" var="e">
                        {
                        title: '{!e}'
                        },
 ]
 });
```

somebody said we can resolve the performance issue by using the addresource event. but i dont know how to implement in the above structure.